# Is there any way to hide components in the layout editor in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm building an app using Android Studio and Java. When I'm trying to make the layout in the Layout Editor is there any way to hide components so I can see better? I don't mean using Java when starting the app, I mean in the editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set

```
tools:visibility="gone|invisible|visible"
```

in xml file

`tools` namespace that enable design-time features so When you build your app, the build tools remove these attributes so there is no effect on your APK size or runtime behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, in XML `tools:visibility="gone"` on the component.

or in the design view to the right of the component name in the component tree you can click and select `tools:visibility` there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ask about the visibility

```
android:visibility="visible|invisibile|gone"
```

Comment: OP asks only about the editor, so it should be `tools:visibility` instead of `android:visibility`